# Outlook for Mac - archive single email with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: email, ms-office

In Thunderbird I can press the "A" key and archive the highlighted email to a folder named after the current year. In Outlook I've seen various ways to move to a folder via a keyboard shortcut and then select the folder to move to (a two step process); I could not find a way to move an email to a particular folder with a single keyboard shortcut.

Is there a way a to move an email to a designated folder with a single keyboard shortcut in Outlook 2016 for Mac?

*Note*: I had previously asked this question at [personal productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/14806/outlook-for-mac-archive-single-email-with-a-keyboard-shortcut) but my question was deemed "too specific".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### Can be done via `Keyboard Shortcuts` under `System Preferences`

Manually move the email once to the folder that you want, say `Archives` by right-clicking the email and choose it or using `Shift Cmd M`. After that `Archives` will start showing as one of the options when you try to another move email.

[image: Make Archives folder available for shortcut]

Once you’ve moved the message the folder becomes a recent item under the Move menu button in Outlook and a keyboard shortcut can now be assigned to it.

Open `Keyboard Shortcuts` under `System Preferences` and assign your favourite keyboard shortcut e.g. `Control-Option-A` to move messages to this folder (`Archives`).

[image: Assign shortcut in System Preferences]

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. Unfortunately this does not work with Outlook 2016 (15.15). Are you able to test it on this version?

Comment: Yes, works for me in outlook 2016. You need to move the one email to your desired folder once by right-clicking it and then `Move`.

Comment: Sorry for my really tardy acceptance of this answer - I could not get the above steps working when I last tried but will try again. On other note the latest version of Outlook for Mac now has *one click* archiving which is not as good as a single keypress but definitely an improvement!

Comment: To make this work on Outlook 16.36 (2020) - I needed to make sure that the shortcut matches *exactly* with what's displayed in the `Move` menu item. So mine said `Archive (myemail@company.com)` - and it worked after pasting that. *Thank you* for this lifesaver answer OP!

Answer (score 28):

This isn't exactly the question you asked, but Ctrl-e is the keyboard shortcut for archiving a message (at least as of Outlook for Mac version 15.36).

Comment: On Windows, Backspace = Archive and Delete = Move to Trash.
When I switched to Mac, used the same and to my surprise, I was deleting emails, not archiving them. Learnt it the hard way that CTRL+E is the proper way to archive...

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: This worked for me on Outlook for Mac v16.24.  Thanks so much for sharing!!! :D

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in v15.30.   Trick is replace "Archives" with the exact folder name.  "Archives" is not a command name but the name of the folder you want the shortcut to move the mail to.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version, you can  Archive with the following shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: In Outlook (V16.16.22) on My Mac CRTL-E just moves the selection to the bottom of the list and COMMAND-E does nothing. Did you, perhaps, set your own keyboard shortcut for the Archive command, or respond with the Outlook for Windows command?

Comment: It's not Command E, it's Control E.